# Angular/C# CORS Issue

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, cors

I hosted my client on localhost:8080/ and server on localhost:44302/

I am trying to link to my backend, but I am getting CORS issue. Below is my **Angular http request**

```
$http.post(url, data, {
    headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, OPTIONS'
             }
}).success(function (response) {
  // rest of the code
}).error(function (err, status) {
  // rest of the code
});
```

On the server side which is written in C#, I have the following set on the response

```
 Response.ContentType = "application/json";
 Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS");
```

Even after setting these, I am getting the following error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:44302/some_uri.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

What am I missing?

Comment: What are you using for backend? ASP.NET Web API? Where did you put the code that modifies the response?

Comment: Yes am using ASP.NET MVC, I put the code in the controller from where I am sending the response back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to send any additional headers from AngularJS. Preflight request will be made for you automatically.

To enable all cross-origin requests in Web API, you can do this:

1. Install NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors.
2. Add the following code to WebApiConfig.cs:

   ```
       var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
       config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
   ```

Full understanding of CORS is worth a few minutes of time. I recommend reading an in-depth tutorial here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Although I did not need this to solve my solution, I will accept it as it gives a clear solution for others. 
For my case, I used a proper IP somewhere instead of localhost, and due to some of Microsoft weird IP issues I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Perform this in your application level server side 
No changes required in your client-side application

Step 1: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

Step 2: From HttpConfiguration object you can enable cors - Applicable for the entire application

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // New code
        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**Alternate**  :

Step 3: Go to controller add this below attribute  - Applicable only to TestController

```
// Allow CORS for all origins. (Caution!)
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

**Example** :

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // Controller methods not shown...
}
```