# Kubernetes Nest CORS Issue

Tags: kubernetes, graphql, cors, nestjs

I am running a react project on Kubernetes and I am having both frontend and backend as services in Kubernetes. The backend is running `nestjs` and `graphql`.

When I tried to spin it up online by using the following url `https://my_backend.mydomain` everything went as expected, though I realized that with this architecture the backend will be publicly available.

So I decided to use the internal url of Kubernetes such as `http://my_service:my_port`, and I got an error: `Blocked loading mixed active content`. I realized it was for http instead of https, re-configured the url and set up the connection for `https://my-service:my_port`. Though now I get a: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource`.

My ingress file looks like the following:

```yaml
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "$http_origin"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "Content-Security-Policy:  https://cdn.jsdelivr.net:* https://*.rsms.me:* https://rsms.me:* always";
      more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *";
spec:
...
```

Am I mistaken somewhere? I could not find that much regarding Kubernets+NestJs+CORS. I keep ending up in documentation that says to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *". But apparently that does not much with my configuration.

Comment: Hi, according to [this site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors) your error should be like `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows
reading the remote resource at https://some-url-here. (Reason:
additional information here).`. What is you additional information?

Comment: (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
My guess is because I am trying to access on `https` a service that is actually on `http` (since internal to Kubernetes). But when trying to access with `http`, I get `Blocked loading mixed active content`. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: I looked at https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/tls-termination/ but I don't want the service to be exposed to the outside. The service should be inside Kubernetes.

Comment: When exactly did you get this error and how did you test it?

Comment: When launching the app online. I noticed it/tested it with the Console of the browser.

Comment: Please share your whole ingress yaml file. Did you use one domain or more? Did you see [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61989301/k8s-angular-cors-issue-rest-server)?